# What's the difference between juju and juju-core?

Tags: juju

I found two projects in Launchpad:

- https://launchpad.net/juju
- https://launchpad.net/juju-core

How are those related, can anybody clarify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Looking at the the both launchpad projects it looks like `juju-core` is the actual source-code of juju written in go which can be found on [Github](https://github.com/juju/juju). When you go the launchpad page of juju-core and you switch to the code tab, you can see it there as well.

The other launchpad project refers to the Juju packages that can be installed to use Juju . Switching to the code tab here does not provide any source code but does give you a link to download the files which can be found [here](https://launchpad.net/juju/+download).